# "Can only iterable" Python error

Tags: python, iterable

Hello my fellow programmers.

I am a fairly new programmer, and now I am facing a great predicament. I am getting the error:

```
can only assign an iterable
```

Firstly I don't know what that means.

Secondly I will leave my code for you professionals to critique it:

```
def num_top(int_lis):
    duplic_int_lis = int_lis
    int_firs= duplic_int_lis [0]
    int_lis[:] = duplic_int_lis [int_firs]
```

Basically I am trying to find the `[0]` element in the list and then using that int as an index position to find the integer at that index position.

Comment: You are trying to assign an integer (I guess from the name) to a list. As the error says: You can only assign to lists (or slices thereof) an iterable and an integer is not iterable.

Comment: `duplic_int_lis = int_lis` does not create a duplicate list.

Comment: @RogerPate .. then how can one go about creating a duplicate list?

Comment: `dupe = list(original)`

Comment: Can you clarify what return value you expect from your function (it currently returns `None`) and what mutation you expect to happen to the input list? Your example `output` could be either of those, but we can't tell which.

Comment: why not just `return int_list[int_list[0]]`

Answer (score 4):

`int_lis[:] = duplic_int_lis [int_firs]` means assign all the items of `duplic_int_lis [int_firs]` to `int_lis`, so it expects you to pass an iterable/iterator on the RHS.

But in your case you're passing it an non-iterable, which is incorrect:

```
>>> lis = range(10)
>>> lis[:] = range(5) 
>>> lis               #all items of `lis` replaced with range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> lis[:] = 5        #Non-iterable will raise an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-77-0704f8a4410d>", line 1, in <module>
    lis[:] = 5
TypeError: can only assign an iterable

>>> lis[:] = 'foobar' #works for any iterable/iterator
>>> lis
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

As you cannot iterate over an integer, hence the error.

```
>>> for x in 1: pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-84-416802313c58>", line 1, in <module>
    for x in 1:pass
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: okay I got the code working... but now the problem is... nothing mutates... it still returns the original list.

Comment: @user2954367 Your question isn't clear actually, please provide some examples in the question body.

Comment: @user2954367 Try `int_lis[int_lis[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The RHS of a slice-assignment must be an iterable, not a scalar. Consider slice-deleting and then appending instead.

Comment: while technically impeccable i'm afraid i can't upvote an answer that is 98% likely to go over the questioner's head...

Comment: no that actually makes sense, only thing is... could you explain slice deleting?

Comment: @user2954367: `del int_lis[:]` This deletes the contents of the list, but leaves the list itself alone. But reading further, it seems that this isn't what you want to do at all.

Comment: well that is sort of what I want.. But I want the integer without the [].. for example now when I run the code the result I get is [3].

Comment: Then you should return the value instead of mutating the list.

Comment: but if I simply return the value... it does return, if I state return (int_lis) .. but it returns the original list if I return (None)

Answer (score 0):

An iterable is a thing with multiple items that you can iterate through (for example: take the 1st value do something, then the 2nd do something, etc...)  Lists, dictionaries, tuples, strings have several items in them and can be used as iterables.  As a counterexample: number types don't qualify as iterable.

Remember that computers count from #0 so: if you want the first value of a list you can use

```
my_list[0]
```

before you go further I would suggest watching this video about looping. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o